# Sub-group of a free group that is characteristic But not totally characteristic

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Looking for a counter example (if it exists) and a reference for further reading. Can there be a subgroup of finite index in a finitely generated free group that is characteristic but not totally characteristic.

> **Definition**: A subgroup $H\le G$ is said to be *totally characteristic* if for all endomorphisms, $\psi\in \text{End}(G)$ we have that $\psi(H)\subseteq H$.

Comment: You should define "totally characteristic"

Comment: Let $G$ be a group and $H$ subgroup. $H$ is called totally characteristic if for every endomorphism $\phi :G\to G$ we have $\phi (H)\subseteq H$

Comment: The only totally characteristic subgroups of free groups are verbal subgroups, so this is equivalent to asking whether all characteristic subgroups of of finite index in free groups are verbal.

Comment: @DerekHolt Do you know of a reference where I can find the proof that totally characteristic subgroups in a free group are vrebel?

Comment: I haven't found a reference for the proof. I found the assertion [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Verbal_subgroup) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup)

Comment: How could be this one (I have no idea in depth): consider free group on 2-generators and fix $n\geq 2$. Take $N$ to be subgroup generated by $n$-th powers of all elements of $F$; this is characteristic (am I right?). Then $F/N$ is a Burnside group, and for some values of $n$, it is known to be *finite group*; in such case, we can pull back some subgroup of $F/N$ which is characteristic but not fully invariant (or totally characteristic); it may work.

Comment: You could try asking this question on mathoverflow?

Comment: Crossposted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269419/